# On special cyclic subgroups of a finite group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be finite group and $x,y\in G$. 
We know that $\langle x, g\rangle$ is cyclic for any $g\in G$. Also  we have $\langle y, t\rangle$ is cyclic for some $t\in G$.
Now prove that $\langle xy, t\rangle$ is cyclic.

My attempt:

we have $\langle x, t\rangle=\langle a_{1}\rangle$  and $\langle y, t\rangle=\langle a_{2}\rangle$ are cyclic. Then $x=a_{1}^{m_{1}},y=a_{2}^{m_{2}}$ for some  natural numbers $m_{1},m_{2}$.

Comment: Hint: $t$ is also some power of both $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $<y,t>=<a_2>$. Now we know that $H:=<x,a_2>$ is cyclic. Clearly $H$ contains $x,y,t$ hence $H$ contains $<xy,t>$, this last group being a subgroup of a cyclic group $H$ will be cyclic as well.

Comment: Yes. very nice. Thank you